# SQL Server 2012 date and time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, ssms

I'm trying to create a simple database for a class but when entering time or date variables, I get an error. My code looks a little like this:

```
USE Music

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Album] ([Length], ReleaseDate, DateAdded)
VALUES ('40:17', '2015/09/18', '2015/10/15 00:00:00.0000')
```

Then I get the following error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

`Length` is stored as `time(0)`, `ReleaseDate` is stored as `date`, and `DateAdded` is stored as `datetime2(4)`.

Can anyone tell me how to correctly format these so my data will be applied?

Answer (score 2):

`Length` has datatype of `time`, which can only store from 0 to 24 hours. But anyhow, I think you meant the album was 40 minutes and 17 seconds long, as opposed to 40 hours and 17 minutes long.

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Album]
       ([Length], ReleaseDate, DateAdded)
VALUES ('00:40:17', '2015/09/18', '2015/10/15 00:00:00.0000')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Album]
       ([Length], ReleaseDate, DateAdded)
VALUES ('00:40:17', '20150918', '20151015')
```